# How to parse json files as html files instead of json?

Tags: conversion, html, json

When downloading the courses from Coursera for offline use using coursera-dl, it downloads the html pages as json files.

These json files display in json format and cannot be parsed with a simply json to table or json to html viewer. I even acquired JsonViewer but it cannot parse them.

I could do it manually, but I need a systematic approach that is simple because there are too many files and courses to do this reasonably by hand, nor is it reasonable to simply print the page to PDF from Coursera - instead I want to take the json files and convert them to a human readable format that displays beautifully like html or a table.

Here is an example json file which displays as HTML on coursera but downloads as a json file:

```
[
    [
        "course-introduction",
        [
            [
                "introduction",
                [
                    [
                        "start-here",
                        {
                            "html": [
                                [
                                    "#inmemory#<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n<co-content>\n <h3 level=\"3\">\n  <strong>\n   Start here\n  </strong>\n </h3>\n <p>\n  Hello,\n </p>\n <p>\n  This page will help you to understand the structure of the course and what you will be required to do for each week.\n </p>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   Structure of the course\n  </strong>\n </p>\n <p>\n  Each week will consist of:\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    1-2 hours of lecture videos\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Some readings\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    A quiz which will relate to the content covered that week\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    There is also a final assignment at the end of the course.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n </p>\n <p>\n  In addition, we will recommend extra reading and video resources if you would like to explore topics further.\n </p>\n <p>\n  The details of each week\u2019s topic can be found on the syllabus page.\n </p>\n <p>\n </p>\n</co-content>\n<style>\n body {\n    padding: 50px 85px 50px 85px;\n}\n\ntable th, table td {\n    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;\n    padding: 5px 20px;\n    text-align: left;\n}\ninput {\n    margin: 10px;\n}\n}\nth {\n    font-weight: bold;\n}\ntd, th {\n    display: table-cell;\n    vertical-align: inherit;\n}\nimg {\n    height: auto;\n    max-width: 100%;\n}\npre {\n    display: block;\n    margin: 20px;\n    background: #424242;\n    color: #fff;\n    font-size: 13px;\n    white-space: pre-wrap;\n    padding: 9.5px;\n    margin: 0 0 10px;\n    border: 1px solid #ccc;\n}\n</style>\n<script async=\"\" src=\"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">\n MathJax.Hub.Config({\n    tex2jax: {\n      inlineMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['$','$'] ],\n      displayMath: [ [\"\\\\[\",\"\\\\]\"] ],\n      processEscapes: true\n    }\n  });\n</script>\n",
                                    "instructions"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "syllabus",
                        {
                            "html": [
                                [
                                    "#inmemory#<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n<co-content>\n <h3 level=\"3\">\n  Syllabus\n </h3>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   1: Why we need to reinvent management\n  </strong>\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Management versus Leadership: what each one is, why we need them both.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Evidence for the failure of management\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    The underlying problem: a social technology that has not evolved.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    The future of management.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Management model: an important concept, the guiding framework for the course.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    What is your management model?\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n </p>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   2. The 'means' of managing\n  </strong>\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Traditional and alternative approaches to coordination.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Traditional and alternative approaches to decision-making.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Trying out these ideas in your company: experiments in emergence and collective wisdom.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n </p>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   3: The 'ends' of managing\n  </strong>\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Traditional and alternative approaches to motivation.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Traditional and alternative approaches to objective-setting.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Trying out these ideas in your company: experiments in motivation and obliquity.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n </p>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   4. Redefining a company's management model\n  </strong>\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Mapping your model, and how you would like it to change.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Forces for change and those that reinforce the status quo.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Top-driven vs Bottom-up change.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Designing and running your own management experiment.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    A broader perspective: how management ideas gain and lose currency.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n </p>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   5. Making it personal: Becoming a better boss\n  </strong>\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    The challenge of managing effectively at an individual level.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    What does a good manager do really?\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Know your employees: see the world through their eyes.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Know yourself: understand your own limitations.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Tips and tricks for becoming a better boss.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n </p>\n</co-content>\n<style>\n body {\n    padding: 50px 85px 50px 85px;\n}\n\ntable th, table td {\n    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;\n    padding: 5px 20px;\n    text-align: left;\n}\ninput {\n    margin: 10px;\n}\n}\nth {\n    font-weight: bold;\n}\ntd, th {\n    display: table-cell;\n    vertical-align: inherit;\n}\nimg {\n    height: auto;\n    max-width: 100%;\n}\npre {\n    display: block;\n    margin: 20px;\n    background: #424242;\n    color: #fff;\n    font-size: 13px;\n    white-space: pre-wrap;\n    padding: 9.5px;\n    margin: 0 0 10px;\n    border: 1px solid #ccc;\n}\n</style>\n<script async=\"\" src=\"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">\n MathJax.Hub.Config({\n    tex2jax: {\n      inlineMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['$','$'] ],\n      displayMath: [ [\"\\\\[\",\"\\\\]\"] ],\n      processEscapes: true\n    }\n  });\n</script>\n",
                                    "instructions"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "grading",
                        {
                            "html": [
                                [
                                    "#inmemory#<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n<co-content>\n <h3 level=\"3\">\n  Grading\n </h3>\n <p>\n  Here is how the final grade for the course will be calculated:\n </p>\n <ol bullettype=\"numbers\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    <strong>\n     Weekly quizzes\n    </strong>\n    (Weighting: 50%)Each weekly quiz will be weighted 10%.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ol>\n <ol bullettype=\"numbers\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    <strong>\n     Final assignment\n    </strong>\n    (Weighting: 50%)Your writing will be peer-assessed and assigned a grade by your fellow students.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ol>\n <p>\n </p>\n</co-content>\n<style>\n body {\n    padding: 50px 85px 50px 85px;\n}\n\ntable th, table td {\n    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;\n    padding: 5px 20px;\n    text-align: left;\n}\ninput {\n    margin: 10px;\n}\n}\nth {\n    font-weight: bold;\n}\ntd, th {\n    display: table-cell;\n    vertical-align: inherit;\n}\nimg {\n    height: auto;\n    max-width: 100%;\n}\npre {\n    display: block;\n    margin: 20px;\n    background: #424242;\n    color: #fff;\n    font-size: 13px;\n    white-space: pre-wrap;\n    padding: 9.5px;\n    margin: 0 0 10px;\n    border: 1px solid #ccc;\n}\n</style>\n<script async=\"\" src=\"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">\n MathJax.Hub.Config({\n    tex2jax: {\n      inlineMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['$','$'] ],\n      displayMath: [ [\"\\\\[\",\"\\\\]\"] ],\n      processEscapes: true\n    }\n  });\n</script>\n",
                                    "instructions"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "week-1",
        [
            [
                "week-1",
                [
                    [
                        "1-1-overview-of-the-course",
                        {
                            "mp4": [
                                [
                                    "https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/MTBOTF_Week%201_Part_1_Overview_of_the_course.93aad670959511e48c457381c363c715/full/540p/index.mp4?Expires=1707523200&Signature=O7lozy19g5K8TwrvLdzcYesEgRWbw9-N~HC~kZCAA4h5JtzOQpc45TVU3H7vZ2FtWyX6XSVsycvkqMDsixSIefRJ1fUPghWIjM2JHYZCHKiQsbV-eGTo9JLVa1zkt0588FDMpN4ajJHxbXT0S3fHf7p~Kfs9oyLUsIIjAGsSUtI_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ],
                            "en.srt": [
                                [
                                    "https://api.coursera.org/api/subtitleAssetProxy.v1/8Bum9_PiT12bpvfz4m9d4A?expiry=1707523200000&hmac=7cofRXNYX4qUBbMGVYBB6ztsp6ITq29St4lnP_Y1_sE&fileExtension=srt",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ],
                            "en.txt": [
                                [
                                    "https://api.coursera.org/api/subtitleAssetProxy.v1/8Bum9_PiT12bpvfz4m9d4A?expiry=1707523200000&hmac=4tsFKHa5HuW4bMTz9_o1bEY_tIVHihGhWgoQTaWuKY0&fileExtension=txt",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "1-2-management-versus-leadership",
                        {
                            "mp4": [
                                [
                                    "https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/MTBOTF_Week_1_Part_2_Management_vs_Leadership.83e55cb0959511e48c457381c363c715/full/540p/index.mp4?Expires=1707523200&Signature=T1UN1gH3A8xVa3KUPklyh--BP5H0VLBIWD4rMOCRAmQz1LhuizK4Ma7YeJYFr2vdXrch6U8WlmNGQ7kegos5erdVdOvvveTn1mkGXrjUJwk10ixZzJUomil7zi0jEbYVUAnHGrkP8u3YBhchG4obwuQAygpD1RqK~qLSvvcTAH4_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ],
                            "en.srt": [
                                [
                                    "https://api.coursera.org/api/subtitleAssetProxy.v1/hRO739DQQVaTu9_Q0LFWgg?expiry=1707523200000&hmac=2I5TxnvNlsWCPJEKz8l_WbiPFtYF1_1Iy8epdLYBYR4&fileExtension=srt",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ],
                            "en.txt": [
                                [
                                    "https://api.coursera.org/api/subtitleAssetProxy.v1/hRO739DQQVaTu9_Q0LFWgg?expiry=1707523200000&hmac=6TBqGpWSHyvr455msOjFUmeztOvuR0PJX4S50_uqRTU&fileExtension=txt",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "videos-from-management-innovation-exchange-mix",
                        {
                            "html": [
                                [
                                    "#inmemory#<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n<co-content>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   Videos from\n  </strong>\n  <a href=\"http://www.managementexchange.com/\" title=\"Link: http://www.managementexchange.com/\">\n   <strong>\n    Management Innovation eXchange (MIX)\n   </strong>\n  </a>\n  <strong>\n   :\n  </strong>\n </p>\n <p>\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    <a href=\"http://www.managementexchange.com/video/vineet-nayar-do-you-want-be-ant-or-butterfly-1\" title=\"Link: http://www.managementexchange.com/video/vineet-nayar-do-you-want-be-ant-or-butterfly-1\">\n     Vineet Nayar: Do you want to be an ant or a butterfly?\n    </a>\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    <a href=\"http://www.managementexchange.com/video/terri-kelly-wl-gores-original-management-model-0\" title=\"Link: http://www.managementexchange.com/video/terri-kelly-wl-gores-original-management-model-0\">\n     Terri Kelly: W.L. Gore's Original Management Model\n    </a>\n    If you have problems with the Terri Kelly video stopping early, you can see the whole video on\n    <a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47yk2upT7tM\" title=\"Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47yk2upT7tM\">\n     YouTube\n    </a>\n    as well.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n </p>\n</co-content>\n<style>\n body {\n    padding: 50px 85px 50px 85px;\n}\n\ntable th, table td {\n    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;\n    padding: 5px 20px;\n    text-align: left;\n}\ninput {\n    margin: 10px;\n}\n}\nth {\n    font-weight: bold;\n}\ntd, th {\n    display: table-cell;\n    vertical-align: inherit;\n}\nimg {\n    height: auto;\n    max-width: 100%;\n}\npre {\n    display: block;\n    margin: 20px;\n    background: #424242;\n    color: #fff;\n    font-size: 13px;\n    white-space: pre-wrap;\n    padding: 9.5px;\n    margin: 0 0 10px;\n    border: 1px solid #ccc;\n}\n</style>\n<script async=\"\" src=\"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">\n MathJax.Hub.Config({\n    tex2jax: {\n      inlineMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['$','$'] ],\n      displayMath: [ [\"\\\\[\",\"\\\\]\"] ],\n      processEscapes: true\n    }\n  });\n</script>\n",
                                    "instructions"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "week-1-slides",
                        {
                            "pdf": [
                                [
                                    "https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_397f11d638de07d2b395a7649b594c47_Week-1_slides_upload.pdf?Expires=1707523200&Signature=UZbPq~8pUkyt4Jmi2ByZ5jcZymLncDzUad~1MEBK74D0wBVxIWceUfdby0Rcw~3Qv~HTgA4n2eWiEN6CjvqU8dCOjGXXit68XV9qi1~ew2QMFvgGYUkwnc-4Asq5SsCog0m6mNO6AUajdIvT0MJxrvial4R3tcw8McoIvrU82xM_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A",
                                    "Week_1_slides_upload"
                                ]
                            ],
                            "html": [
                                [
                                    "#inmemory#<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n<co-content>\n <h3 level=\"3\">\n  Week 1 slides\n </h3>\n <p>\n  You can find all the slides for week 1 here\n </p>\n <asset assettype=\"generic\" extension=\"pdf\" id=\"D9U946TkEeWVNArF_-1Xgw\" name=\"Week 1_slides_upload\">\n </asset>\n <p>\n </p>\n</co-content>\n<style>\n body {\n    padding: 50px 85px 50px 85px;\n}\n\ntable th, table td {\n    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;\n    padding: 5px 20px;\n    text-align: left;\n}\ninput {\n    margin: 10px;\n}\n}\nth {\n    font-weight: bold;\n}\ntd, th {\n    display: table-cell;\n    vertical-align: inherit;\n}\nimg {\n    height: auto;\n    max-width: 100%;\n}\npre {\n    display: block;\n    margin: 20px;\n    background: #424242;\n    color: #fff;\n    font-size: 13px;\n    white-space: pre-wrap;\n    padding: 9.5px;\n    margin: 0 0 10px;\n    border: 1px solid #ccc;\n}\n</style>\n<script async=\"\" src=\"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">\n MathJax.Hub.Config({\n    tex2jax: {\n      inlineMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['$','$'] ],\n      displayMath: [ [\"\\\\[\",\"\\\\]\"] ],\n      processEscapes: true\n    }\n  });\n</script>\n",
                                    "instructions"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "week-1-reading",
                        {
                            "pdf": [
                                [
                                    "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/futuremanagement/Week%201%20reading%20beyond%20the%20knowledge%20era.pdf",
                                    "Week_1_reading_beyond_the_knowledge_era"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/futuremanagement/Week%201_reading_Reinventing_Management_extract.pdf",
                                    "Week_1_reading_Reinventing_Management_extract"
                                ]
                            ],
                            "html": [
                                [
                                    "#inmemory#<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n<co-content>\n <h3 level=\"3\">\n  Week 1 reading\n </h3>\n <p>\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    <a href=\"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/futuremanagement/Week%201%20reading%20beyond%20the%20knowledge%20era.pdf\" title=\"Link: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/futuremanagement/Week%201%20reading%20beyond%20the%20knowledge%20era.pdf\">\n     Beyond the Knowledge Era\n    </a>\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    <a href=\"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/futuremanagement/Week%201_reading_Reinventing_Management_extract.pdf\" title=\"Link: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/futuremanagement/Week%201_reading_Reinventing_Management_extract.pdf\">\n     Why Management Failed \u2013 And How It Can Be Reinvented\n    </a>\n    (Extract from\n    <em>\n     Reinventing Management\n    </em>\n    , Chapter 1)\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n  <strong>\n   Optional Additional Reading\n  </strong>\n  If you'd like to further explore this week's topics, you might want to have a look at the following texts:\n </p>\n <ul bullettype=\"bullets\">\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Gary Hamel, 2008, \u201cThe Future of Management\u201d, Harvard Business Press\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Julian Birkinshaw, 2012 \u201cReinventing Management\u201d, Jossey Bass.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n  <li>\n   <p>\n    Henry Mintzberg, 2009, \u201cManaging\u201d, Berrett Koelher.\n   </p>\n  </li>\n </ul>\n <p>\n  <em>\n   Please note that we only provide recommendations for optional additional readings, not the materials.\n  </em>\n </p>\n</co-content>\n<style>\n body {\n    padding: 50px 85px 50px 85px;\n}\n\ntable th, table td {\n    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;\n    padding: 5px 20px;\n    text-align: left;\n}\ninput {\n    margin: 10px;\n}\n}\nth {\n    font-weight: bold;\n}\ntd, th {\n    display: table-cell;\n    vertical-align: inherit;\n}\nimg {\n    height: auto;\n    max-width: 100%;\n}\npre {\n    display: block;\n    margin: 20px;\n    background: #424242;\n    color: #fff;\n    font-size: 13px;\n    white-space: pre-wrap;\n    padding: 9.5px;\n    margin: 0 0 10px;\n    border: 1px solid #ccc;\n}\n</style>\n<script async=\"\" src=\"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n</script>\n<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">\n MathJax.Hub.Config({\n    tex2jax: {\n      inlineMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['$','$'] ],\n      displayMath: [ [\"\\\\[\",\"\\\\]\"] ],\n      processEscapes: true\n    }\n  });\n</script>\n",
                                    "instructions"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "week-1-summary",
                        {
                            "mp4": [
                                [
                                    "https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/Week1_summary_v2.6c0e4020adfa11e4b35a2b1fb2a97c1c/full/540p/index.mp4?Expires=1707523200&Signature=an-p8LDwCxVO8LiVoDknwSTE-UQH87ibSQsaM3KvEOngiZGsZqUQrWTtbkJcLCRqJMZrTZrcz3ty-kKerFLEpV0a5MPTVwvFkqWfvqvioqG6NtnmB~UKEqTS4X3TDtQKfWX0XUtqW65q7iObnMVr6-RazT-U47kvxprqD-P263s_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ],
                            "en.srt": [
                                [
                                    "https://api.coursera.org/api/subtitleAssetProxy.v1/gaAW9sdGTHKgFvbHRoxytw?expiry=1707523200000&hmac=YcOUeuJtns7fddhrksNItOa9kZkcEuEkigjj8DhDPnY&fileExtension=srt",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ],
                            "en.txt": [
                                [
                                    "https://api.coursera.org/api/subtitleAssetProxy.v1/gaAW9sdGTHKgFvbHRoxytw?expiry=1707523200000&hmac=mfmowEIpyeEe3qr87LW9urXFedi86QaDn5BfU6mh8Mg&fileExtension=txt",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can I systematically convert these files in bulk to a beautiful human readable format in either in a table or html file?

Comment: Why convert these files? Why not simply download the HTML?

Comment: Because there are tens of thousands. That's why I said, *"because there are too many files and courses to do this reasonably by hand"*

Comment: What do you mean? If one goes to https://www.coursera.org/search?query=generative%20ai&sortBy=NEW, for example, and selects *Save page to file* in a browser, the whole page is downloaded as HTML, not as JSON. Pleas *edit the question* to explain what you are doing and what you want.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it's supposed to look like? `coursera-dl` is supposed to process that .json file itself to download the individual resources. What is the full command you're running to download the course, and your `coursera-dl.conf` (if using one)?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale You must be confused. coursera-dl is doing what it's supposed to. I want to create a systematic way to convert already downloaded json to html files that can be more easily viewed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You have not read the question and that is not what I am asking. You don't understand the question so please do not offer any more solutions until you read the question title. This is about converting json files to html. Not about saving a page from a website.

Comment: I ask because your example json file contains multiple lines of html content (The lines starting with `"#inmemory#`). It would be easy enough to script exporting those lines to individual html files, but it sounds more like you want to convert the entire thing to a single viewable page? If so, that would require some kind of tool to build out html data for each element, like https://github.com/pgrabovets/json-view

Comment: It seems to me this is asking for assistance circumventing controls on protected content, something this site doesn't typically assist with.

Comment: First of all you can only download when you are a paid user for courses you paid for, and second of all, it's literally none of your business what people do with it, so why don't you just go back where you came from, we don't want you here